# Why does my Shimano Nexus 8i need readjustment after every gear shift?

Tags: shimano, gears, internally-geared-hub, nexus, barrel-adjuster

Since a month or two, almost every time I change gear my Shimano Nexus 8i becomes "unadjusted". I have readjusted it dozens of time but the problem persists. The gear is really easy to adjust (set it to fourth gear, adjust two lines so they line up by screwing a "nut" on the lever) but as soon as I have shifted the gear a couple of times the lines no longer line up (they end up being wrongly adjusted in both directions).

What can cause this? Dirt in the shifting cable (Is that the correct term? The "hose" that the wire runs into.)? How to fix?

I have seen [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/nexus-hub-keeps-getting-misaligned) but that situation is different. I can adjust using the barrel adjuster (which didn't work for [Pedro](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/4514/pedro) posting that question), OTOH, my misalignment appear immediately after adjusting (which it didn't for Pedro).

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should change the gear cable. A small amount of corrosion and/or grit can produce a significant shifting error.

Comment: @JoeK Yes, that was kind of my plan, although I would like to try to clean it before taking that step. Is that possible? Remove the wire from the cable that surrounds it and clean both?

Comment: @d-b you could first try to loosen both ends of the cable, insert a few drops of oil, and then move the inner cable back and forth until it's moving smoothly.

Comment: If you change the cable you'd better change the housing as well.

Comment: @Carel Why is that necessary? Just curious.

Comment: @d-b Cable housings 'suffer', they age, there's water ingress, rusting, rubbing of metal against metal causing wear. It's accepted practice to change housings from time to time, especially if the bike has lived outdoors or in a moist place most of the time, ridden in adverse weather conditions and through the winter as well.